Function returning 101 and -101 instead of 1 and -1
So my professor gave us the assignment to code a function that works exactly like strcmp() but without using any library functions. I came up with the following code but instead of returning 1 or -1 when one of the strings is longer than the other one, the output shows 101 and -101.
#include <stdio.h>

int string_compare(char v[], char w[]) {
    int sizeV = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);
    int sizeW = sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]);

    if(sizeV == sizeW) {
        int i;
        int x = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < sizeV; i++) {
            if(v[i] != w[i]) {
                x = v[i] - w[i];
                break;
            }
        }

        return x;

    } else return (sizeV > sizeW) ? 1 : -1;
}

int main(void) {
    
    printf("'abcd', 'abcD': %d", string_compare("abcd", "abcD"));
    printf("\n'abcd', 'abcde': %d", string_compare("abcd", "abcde"));
    printf("\n'abcde', 'abcd': %d", string_compare("abcde", "abcd"));
    printf("\n'', '': %d", string_compare("", ""));
    printf("\n'abcd', 'abcd': %d", string_compare("abcd", "abcd"));

    return 0;
}

This is the output i get:
'abcd', 'abcD': 32
'abcd', 'abcde': -101
'abcde', 'abcd': 101
'', '': 0
'abcd', 'abcd': 0


When arrays/strings are passed to a function they decay into pointers. sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]) will not give you the length of the string. You need to use strlen for that (assuming you have zero terminated strings).

"return x;" What's the value set to x, do it piece by piece with print of intermediary value if needed (like print x in the for loop), you'll see your issue.

"works exactly like strcmp()" .... but strcmp does not return only -1, 0, or 1 so keep that in mind :)

Unrelated: don't start output with newline (printf("\n%d %d %d", a, b, c);) but rather end them with a newline (printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);)

Use strlen or pass the length together with the pointer. Put in printf("sizes v=%d w=%d\n", sizeV, sizeW); and you will see that sizeof() always returns the same number, thus you always end up with the if condition being true etc. etc.

You do not actually need to know the lengths of the strings being compared. Just keep checking the characters at successive positions in the two strings until there is a difference or a null terminator character is encountered in one of the strings. (It is only necessary to check one of the strings for a null terminator character.) The result depends on the difference of the character values at the last position checked. (If the strings are identical, this will be comparing the two null terminator characters, which are equal.) Also the characters need to be interpreted as unsigned char.

I think the suggested dupe is not a good one. It discusses arrays only, and here we have zero-terminated strings which gives the oppotunity to use strlen. Voted to re-open.

An acid test for your code would be: printf("\n'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYz': %d\n", string_compare("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYz")); — your code will report the strings as equal; it would stop comparing after H.

return (sizeV > sizeW) ? 1 : -1; is very strange.  (which is to say, it's wrong).  strcmp does not base its return value solely on the length of the strings if they do not match, it compares them using the ordering of the appropriate locale.

@WilliamPursell "it compares them using the ordering of the appropriate locale" Are you certain strcmp() has a locale dependency?  I do not see that in "The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2".  Maybe you are thinking of strcoll()?

@chux You are correct.  It seems that strcmp ignores the locale.

There are multiple problems:

sizeof is inappropriate to compute the length of arrays passed as function arguments: the function just receives a pointer, despite the array-like syntax.  Test for the null terminator instead.

the return value can be any integer value, what matters is whether it is negative, zero or positive.


Here is a modified version:
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int string_compare(const char *v, const char *w) {
    const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *)v;
    const unsigned char *q = (const unsigned char *)w;
    while (*p && *p == *q) {
        p++;
        q++;
    }
#if UCHAR_MAX < INT_MAX
    return *p - *q;  // faster for most architectures
#else
    return (*p > *q) - (*p < *q);  // correct for other cases
#endif
}

int signof(int n) {
    return n == 0 ? 0 : n < 0 ? -1 : 1;
}

void test(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    printf("'%s', '%s': %d\n", s1, s2, signof(string_compare(s1, s2)));
}

int main(void) {
    test("abcd", "abcD");
    test("abcd", "abcde");
    test("abcde", "abcd");
    test("", "");
    test("abcd", "abcd");
    return 0;
}


UV for correct unsigned compare of of characters. Pedantically (*p >*q) - (*p < *q) better than *p - *q to handle characters the same size of int/unsigned (some odd ball graphic processors).

The problem is caused by the way you calculate the length of the strings here:
int sizeV = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);
int sizeW = sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]);

When strings or arrays are passed into a function they decay into pointers.
Therefore sizeof(v) and sizeof(w) are the sizes of pointers, not the character arrays which represent the strings.
Since your strings are zero-terminated, you should use strlen instead:
size_t sizeV = strlen(v);
size_t sizeW = strlen(w);

Note that the type of sizeV and sizeW should be size_t (this is true even if using sizeof was correct).
Live demo


works exactly like strcmp()   (OP)

int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.
C23dr § 7.26.4.2 3

sizeof of pointer is not string length
strcmp() does not return a negative or positive value depending on string length, but on the difference of the first not common character.
String length determination obliges a walk down the length of the string.  In any case, it is not useful to determine their lengths.  Better to walk the strings and compare as we go.

Aside from the sizeof issue mentioned by others, code has additional requirements not met by OP.
Some not mentioned by other answers:
strcmp() only reads the strings
Use const char * in the function parameters to allow use of const strings.
// int string_compare(char v[], char w[]) {
int strcmp(const char v[], const char w[]) {

Compare as unsigned
Use a proper compare.  Compare as if characters were unsigned char.   It can make a difference when the characters in the string differ in sign.

For all functions in this subclause, each character shall be interpreted as if it had the type unsigned char (and therefore every possible object representation is valid and has a different value).
C23dr § 7.26.1 4

// x = v[i] - w[i];
x = ((unsigned *) v)[i] - ((unsigned *) w)[i];

Pedantic: cope with rare platforms where size/range of characters is that of int/unsigned
Avoid subtraction of the characters as the difference may be out of int range.

Putting this all together:
int my_strcmp(const char *x, const char *y) {
  const unsigned char *ux = (const unsigned char*) x;
  const unsigned char *uy = (const unsigned char*) y;
  while (*ux == *uy && *ux) {
    ux++;
    uy++;
  }
  return (*ux > *uy) - (*ux < *uy);
}



So my professor gave us the assignment to code a function that works
exactly like strcmp()

So the first thing you should do is read the description of the standard function strcmp.
It is declared the following way
int strcmp(const char *s1, const char *s2);

That is the both function parameters have the qualifier const. The same way your function string_compare must be declared.
And according to the C Standard:

1 The sign of a nonzero value returned by the comparison functions
memcmp, strcmp, and strncmp is determined by the sign of the
difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both
interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the objects being
compared.

Moreover your function has a bug and a logical error relative to the quote provided above.
This function declaration
int string_compare(char v[], char w[]) {

is equivalent to
int string_compare(char *v, char *w) {

because function parameters having array types are adjusted to pointers to array element types.
Thus these lines
int sizeV = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);
int sizeW = sizeof(w) / sizeof(w[0]);

are equivalent to
int sizeV = sizeof( char * ) / sizeof( char );
int sizeW = sizeof( char * ) / sizeof(char );

that in turn are equivalent to
int sizeV = sizeof( char * );
int sizeW = sizeof( char * );

because sizeof( char ) is always equal to 1.
That is instead of determining lengths of the passed strings you are calculating the size of a pointer.
The logical error is present in this if-else statement
if(sizeV == sizeW) {
   //...
} else //...

If the length of one string is less than the length of other string it does not mean that the first string is less than the second string (see the quote from the C Standard).
As for your code then the expression in the if statement
if(sizeV == sizeW) {

is always evaluated to logical true because it is equivalent to the  expression
if(sizeof( char * ) == sizeof( char * )) {

as explained above.
It follows that you need not to calculate lengths of the passed strings.
The function can be very simple and look the following way
int string_compare(const char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    while ( *s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2 )
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    return ( unsigned char )*s1 - ( unsigned char )*s2;
}

Pay attention to that according to the provided above quote and according to the description of the function strcmp itself in the C Standard:

Returns
3 The strcmp function returns an integer greater than, equal to, or
less than zero, accordingly as the string pointed to by s1 is greater
than, equal to, or less than the string pointed to by s2.

the function is not required to return exactly -1 or 1 if two strings are unequal each other.
Also introducing additional two pointers within the function as it is shown in some other answers like
const unsigned char *p = (const unsigned char *)v;
const unsigned char *q = (const unsigned char *)w;

is just redundant. You need to cast characters of the type char to the type unsigned char only when you perform the

difference between the values of the first pair of characters (both
interpreted as unsigned char) that differ in the objects being
compared*

Here is a demonstration program that shows using the shown above implementation of the function string_compare compared with using the standard C function strcmp.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int string_compare( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    while (*s1 != '\0' && *s1 == *s2)
    {
        ++s1;
        ++s2;
    }

    return ( unsigned char )*s1 - ( unsigned char )*s2;
}

int main( void )
{
    char *first  = "abcd";
    char *second = "abcD";
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, string_compare( first, second ) );
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, strcmp( first, second ) );

    first  = "abcd"; 
    second = "abcde";
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, string_compare( first, second ) );
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, strcmp( first, second ) );

    first  = "abcde";
    second = "abcd";
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, string_compare( first, second ) );
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, strcmp( first, second ) );

    first = "";
    second = "";
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, string_compare( first, second ) );
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, strcmp( first, second ) );

    first = "abcd";
    second = "abcd";
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, string_compare( first, second ) );
    printf( "\"%s\", \"%s\": %d\n", first, second, strcmp( first, second ) );
}

If to use for example the compiler clang then the program output is
"abcd", "abcD": 32
"abcd", "abcD": 32
"abcd", "abcde": -101
"abcd", "abcde": -101
"abcde", "abcd": 101
"abcde", "abcd": 101
"", "": 0
"", "": 0
"abcd", "abcd": 0
"abcd", "abcd": 0

As you can see the output of the function string_compare and of the standard C function strcmp is fully coincide.
Opposite to clang strcmp used in the MS VS C++ indeed generates only three values -1, 0, 1.
"abcd", "abcD": 32
"abcd", "abcD": 1
"abcd", "abcde": -101
"abcd", "abcde": -1
"abcde", "abcd": 101
"abcde", "abcd": 1
"", "": 0
"", "": 0
"abcd", "abcd": 0
"abcd", "abcd": 0 

that is not required by the C Standard as it was stated in the provided quotes.

int sizeV = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);
int sizeV = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);

does not deliver what you want:
sizeof(v) is the size of the pointer, not the string length.
On a machine with a 64-bit architecture: sizeof(v) == 8, sizeof(v[0]) == 1.
Use strlen() or create a loop to find out the string length.

You have lots of errors. sizeof will not work because after passing the array, it descends into a pointer.
Your code assumes that in case the length of the strings are different, then that information by itself decides the comparison. However, that's not true. Consider 'aaaa' and 'zzz'. We know the first is longer than the second, but we also know the first is lesser than the second.
Your line of
x = v[i] - w[i];

computes the actual distance and does not normalize it to -1 and/or 1. This is a solution I have implemented:
#include <stdio.h>

int string_compare(char v[], char w[]) {
    while ((*v != '\0') && (*w != '\0')) {
        if (*v != *w) {
            return (*v < *w) ? -1 : 1;
        }
        v++;
        w++;
    }
    if ((*v == '\0') && (*w == '\0')) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return (*v == '\0') ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    
    printf("'abcd', 'abcD': %d", string_compare("abcd", "abcD"));
    printf("\n'abcd', 'abcde': %d", string_compare("abcd", "abcde"));
    printf("\n'abcde', 'abcd': %d", string_compare("abcde", "abcd"));
    printf("\n'', '': %d", string_compare("", ""));
    printf("\n'abcd', 'abcd': %d", string_compare("abcd", "abcd"));

    return 0;
}

Explanation:

we treat v and w as pointers, after all, they are pointers
we have a loop that evaluates the comparison character-by-character, so at each character

if the characters differ, then we have our result based on which is greater than the other
afterwards we increment both pointers, so they will point to the next character


after the loop we found out that all existent character pairs matched
so if they have the same length, then the two strings are equal
otherwise we can compare by length


The && (*w != '\0') part of the loop test is useless and the last five lines of string_compare can be simplified into a single return (*w == '\0') ? 0 : -1;

@chqrlie it's more readable this way. We can surely compress the code into less lines and operations and it makes sense if the function is so performance-sensitive that such microoptimizations become necessary. But, doing this would make the code less readable.
